# What is the brace depth?

Tags: bibtex

Consider the following definition of [special characters](http://illuminatedcomputing.com/manpj/bibtex.html#lbAD):

> A special character is an escape sequence immediately surrounded by braces, like `{\'E}` or `{\LaTeX}`. In spite of the braces, a special character is considered brace depth 0. However, special characters must themselves appear at brace depth 0; if they are surrounded by other braces, they are not considered special characters. For example, suppose we wanted to correct the example above by using the `\LaTeX` macro. Then we write:
>
> ```
> The {\LaTeX} {C}ompanion
> ```
>
> Here, "C" is at brace depth 1, and everything else, even the special character `\LaTeX`, is at brace depth 0. Now suppose we wrote the title like this:
>
> ```
> The {{\LaTeX}} {C}ompanion
> ```
>
> In this case, `{\LaTeX}` is not a special character, because it starts at brace depth 1, not 0. The string `\LaTeX` is considered to be at brace depth 2.

This seems reasonable enough, but I am confounded by one example I in the BibTeX manual [Tame The BeaST](http://tug.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf), with the following example of different ways to render École:

> For encoding an accent in a title, say É (in upper case) as in the French word École, we’ll write
>   `{\’{E}}cole`, `{\’E}cole` or `{{\’E}}cole`, depending on whether we want it to be turned to lower
>   case (the first two solutions) or not (the last one).

It seems to me that the accented character final example, `{{\’E}}cole` has brace depth 2 and is not a special character.

Also I found an example in arXiv that seems to contradict: `author = {{Chru{\\'s}ci{\\'n}ski}, D. and {Kossakowski}, A.},`.

What is the brace depth of these strings, and are they special characters?

Comment: Do you find that definition of `special character` helpful? Because it seems quite unhelpful to me. I find it just confusing and certainly misleading, given that they clearly don't mean `special characters` in the ordinary TeX sense. (In that sense `\ ` (ignore the space) is a special character, as are `{` and `}`, but `{}` is not a character at all.

Comment: The first link you gave explicitly states that it contradicts the description given in Tame the BeaST, and that the Tame the BeaST one is wrong. In view of that, perhaps it is not surprising you find it confusing when comparing the two sources?

Comment: The examples in arXiv are typed in wrongly. A surname in braces is a very bad mistake. On the net you can also find sites promoting flatness of the Earth, but this doesn't mean they're right, does it?

Comment: @egreg wouldn't you use braces to maintain the case in "McDonald"?  Or what would you do?  I've only had to address issues like that in bib**la**tex for the last few years so can't remember.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to “Tame the BeaST”,

> A *special character* is a part of a field starting with a left brace at brace depth 0 immediately followed by a backslash and ending with the corresponding right brace.

I should note that the brace that delimit the whole field are not taken into account for computing the brace depth, as they're removed when examining the field's contents. This should be clear because the delimiting braces can be substituted with `"..."`.

Thus `{\'E}cole` and `{\'{E}}cole` both start with a special character, but `{{\'E}}cole` doesn't.

In a `title` field, if you don't want the E to be turned lowercase, use the third method. In an author field *always* use the “special character” way, because it will work with sorting and in making abbreviations with the `abbrv` bib style.

Typing an author's surname like in the examples you show is wrong:

```
author = {{Kossakowski}, A.}
```

has the surname consisting of a single token;

```
author = {{Chru{\\'s}ci{\\'n}ski}, D.}
```

has several errors, but even if typed as

```
author = {{Chru{\'s}ci{\'n}ski}, D.}
```

the `\'s` would not be a special character and so probably misunderstood as far as sorting is concerned.

There is absolutely no need to brace surnames; BibTeX styles usually don't apply uppercasing or lowercasing to the `author` field and, if they do, you *want* that the letters are subject to treatment. Thus, if you use `{Chru{\'s}ci{\'n}ski}` and the bib style uppercases surnames, you'd end with “CHRUśCIńSKI”, which you most likely don't want.

Something like “McDonald” is different: such a surname should be typed as

```
author = {M{c}Donald, X.}
```

in case we don't want the “c” to be uppercased in case the style does it.

Comment: So one point of confusion for me is that `{{\'E}}cole` is rendered as `École` and not `\'Ecole`. Escape sequences are not special characters I guess...?

Comment: @Maarten They're written literally to the `.bbl` file, for being interpreted by LaTeX.